# Eclipse JavaScript Development Tools vs Dynamic Languages Toolkit JavaScript IDE

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Except JSDT being the first choice when searching for "Eclipse Javascript" I was not able to locate any information on which is better or the major differences between them.

Any insight would be appreciated; below is a screenshoot of the outline for   Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Javascript IDE    (left) and JavaScript Development Tools (right).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you that you use **JSDT** because it's a **very active project** since last years. More JSDT Team have planned to support Grunt, Gulp, NPM, bower in the Eclipse Neon.

If you need advanced completion, validation for JavaScript please try [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started) which is based on JSDT